# Add X Y Data not populating attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, coordinates

I am adding X Y data to ArcMap using .csv files.

These files contain the X and Y co-ords along with a text column describing each point.

The points are added to the map correctly as an events layer, but when I view the attribute table, only the column headers are shown (see attached photo).

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is occurring because of the CSV file you're using. The column headings will have spaces and/or illegal characters within it, which is why it is not being displayed correctly on the event layer. 
You need to edit these within the CSV.

Please see this [link](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000005588) about field characters within arcmap.

> For ArcGIS to work with multiple data types, certain characters in
>   field or table names are not supported. These characters include
>   spaces, hyphens, such as in the term 'x-coord', brackets, and other
>   special characters. These limits are imposed so that ArcGIS is able to
>   function with the maximum amount of data types.
>
> • Eliminate any characters that are not alphanumeric character or an
>   underscore.  • Do not start field or table names with an underscore or
>   a number. • It is necessary to edit the field names in delimited text
>   files to remove unsupported characters before using them.
>
> The limit for the length of field and table names depends on the
>   underlying database management system (DBMS). Consult the DBMS
>   documentation for information on naming limits for a particular DBMS.
>   A dBASE field name can be up to 10 characters long, and there is no
>   limit on the length of the table name.
>
> • For coverages, use up to 16 letters or numbers. Coverage items or
>   field names must begin with a letter, and cannot contain spaces.

Answer (score 6):

ArcMap does **not** like spaces in field names.

In Excel or a text editor, open your CSV and remove the spaces (and possibly also the dot) and resave, then open in ArcMap again using Add X/Y.

You will probably need to close ArcMap completely to remove locks on your CSV file.